# Scala substring and store it in a DF

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to split a string in scala and store it in a DF to use it with Apache Spark. The string that I have is the following:

```
fromTo: NT=xxx_bt_bsns_m,OD=ntis,OS=wnd,SX=xs,SZ=ddp,
fromTo: NT=xds_bt2_bswns_m,OD=nis,OS=wnd,SX=xs,SZ=ddp,
fromTo: NT=xxa_bt1_b1ns_m,OD=nts,OS=nd,SX=xs,SZ=ddp
```

I just want to get the following substrings :

```
xxx_bt_bsns_m
xds_bt2_bswns_m
xxa_bt1_b1ns_m
```

and then store it in a DF to show something like:

```
+--------------------+
|       Name         |
+--------------------+
|   xxx_bt_bsns_m    |
|  xds_bt2_bswns_m   |
|   xxa_bt1_b1ns_m   |
+--------------------+
```

So what i have to try to get all the string that start with NT and ends with a "," maybe using a pattern with regex and then store it in a DF?

I am starting with scala so for this reason i am having doubts with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using an UDF:

```
val rgx = "^fromTo: NT=([a-zA-Z0-9_]+),(.*)".r

val udfToExtract = udf { str : String => str match { case (rgx(gr1, _)) => gr1} }
```

it gives:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|text                                                 |textNew      |
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|fromTo: NT=xxx_bt_bsns_m,OD=ntis,OS=wnd,SX=xs,SZ=ddp,|xxx_bt_bsns_m|
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Or using regex_extract:

```
df.select(regexp_extract($"text", "^fromTo: NT=([a-zA-Z0-9_]+),(.*)", 1).as("textNew")).show()
```

It gives also:

```
+-------------+
|      textNew|
+-------------+
|xxx_bt_bsns_m|
+-------------+
```